# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Как вы думаете, следует ли ставить запятую в следующем предложении: "В общем(,) мы нашли настоящие таланты". Своё мнение обоснуйте.

Answer (score 1):

**Запятую ставить следует**, поскольку **в общем** - вводное слово со значением «короче говоря, словом; в сущности, по существу». Сравните: *В общем, неважнецки я живу, Иван.* В. Шукшин, Два письма. *Местечковцы охотились давно, и обитатели леса, в общем, неплохо научились спасаться от их охоты.* В. Быков, Лесное счастье.

Но не нужно смешивать вводное слово **в общем** с употреблением в роли члена предложения (в знач. «в общих чертах, в целом, не вдаваясь в детали»). Например: *Директив дать туда не успели, только напомнили в общем, что следует делать.* Д. Фурманов, Чапаев. *Путь свой сюда солдат в общем помнил, он пролегал вдоль речки.* В. Быков, Волчья яма.
(Грамота.ру)

Comment: Вы говорили о предложении "В общем(,)мы нашли настоящие таланты"?

Comment: Да, это ответ на Ваш вопрос. В Вашем предложении запятая нужна: "В общем, мы нашли настоящие таланты".

Answer (score 0):

Здесь нужна. Так как словосочетание " в общем" используется как наречие. Не нужна была бы, если бы это словосочетание использовалось как прилагательное, но в этом случае далее должно было бы идти существительное.

Comment: А если учесть, что данное сочетание имеет значение "в результате", запятая ставиться будет?(Сделал несколько замечаний относительно разных мелочей, но в общем очень хвалил (Гарш.) («в результате»).

Comment: Если "в общем" - наречие, это не объясняет постановку запятой :-) Нужно учитывать в данной ситуации не отнесенность слова к какой-либо части речи, а синтаксическую роль. Только тогда можно объяснить постановку знаков препинания.

Comment: Я тоже считаю, что "в общем" наречием быть ну никак не может!